# EventEmiter pausing and restarting

Tags: dart, angular, angular2-forms

I have the following code

### .html

```
<input
    type = "text"
    #raceCtrl = "ngForm"
    [ngFormControl] = "raceForm.controls['raceCtrl']"
    [(ngModel)] = "race.race"
    (input) = "inputHandler()"
    (mousemove) = "inputHandler()"
    class = "mdl-textfield__input"
    id = "race">

<input
    type = "text"
    #ethnicGroupCtrl = "ngForm"
    [ngFormControl] = "raceForm.controls['ethnicGroupCtrl']"
    [(ngModel)] = "race.ethnicGroup"
    (input) = "inputHandler()"
    (mousemove) = "inputHandler()"
    class = "mdl-textfield__input"
    id = "ethnicGroup">
```

### .dart

```
RaceComponent( FormBuilder fb, ModelService modelSrvc ) {
    raceForm = fb.group( {
      'raceCtrl': ['', CustomValidators.requiredNounValidator( 2 )],
      'ethnicGroupCtrl': ['', CustomValidators.optionalNounValidator( 2 )]
    } );

    _raceCtrl = raceForm.controls['raceCtrl'];
    race = modelSrvc.getRace( );
    inputHandler( );
  }

  void inputHandler( ) {
    if ( raceForm.valid &&
        !isEmpty( _raceCtrl.value ) ) {
      isFormValid = true;
    }
    else {
      isFormValid = false;
    }
    race.isValid = isFormValid;
  }

  onSubmit( ) {
    isSubmitted = true;
    if ( isFormValid ) {
      raceEmitter.emit( {'topic': topic, 'race': race} );
    }
    else {
      raceEmitter.emit( {'topic': topic, 'race': new Race( )} );
    }

    raceMap = new JsonObject.fromJsonString( encode( race ) );
```

The form submits as expected. But from then onwards the stream remains open and even when `ethinicGroup` has errors the error is propagated by the stream to storage. Is it possible to pause and unpause the stream depending on the validity of the form to prevent the erroneous data from being propagated.

Comment: "error is propagated by the stream to storage" I can't see what error is propagated to what stream and what "stream remains open".

Comment: 'error' meaning the invalid input. I would like to prevent the stream from emitting the invalid input.

Comment: What stream? I don't get it.

Comment: `EventEmitter raceEmitter = new EventEmitter( );` extends `Stream`

Comment: It only emits a even when `onSubmit()` is called. I don't see how this is related to your question.

Comment: Once I pressed the submit button, the event is submitted as expected. After that, the event is still being submitted irrespective of the validation result. Is there a way to prevent the invalid data being sent by the emitter?

Comment: Just wrap the `raceEmitter.emit(...)` in an `if(someThing)` than the event is not emitted if `someThing` is `false`.